# Python: How to do math operations with a list imported from a text file?

Tags: python, list

I'm having trouble figuring out how to do math with a list from a text file I imported into Python, the following is the few code I have, I don't know exactly where to start.

```
myfile = open("USPopulation.txt", "r")
numbers = myfile.readlines()

print(numbers)


myfile.close()
```

I plan on figuring out the average annual change, year with greatest increase, and year with smallest increase. Any information would be helpful.

Comment: Can you provide some sample contents of the `USPopulation.txt` ? No clue what data you have.

Comment: You will need to convert the strings to an actual numeric type, e.g. `int`, `float` before you do any mathematical operations on them, e.g. `numbers = list(map(int, myfile)))`. And you may want to look into the `with` statement and context managers: `with open(...) as myfile:`

Comment: @Raptor Samples would be 151868
153982
156393
158956
161884
165069
168088

Comment: If you had a list like this: `numbers = [12, 16, 15, 17]` do you know how to compute values you need? Or the question is how to compute them in general?

Comment: @Pavel To compute them in general, I apologize, I should have been more clear

Answer (score 1):

You're not giving the full information on your data, so I'll make a guess
here and go from there.

Because you talk about finding average annual change etc, I'm assuming that your
data file actually contains two columns: year and population count. E.g. using
your sample numbers:

```
# USPopulation.txt
2000 51868
2001 153982
2002 156393
2003 158956
2004 161884
2005 165069
2006 168088
```

(these don't really make sense, but it doesn't affect the discussion)

The best way to do numerical calculation of this sort is to use [numpy](http://www.numpy.org) (or, for more elaborate things, [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org))

```
>>> import numpy as np
```

Numpy includes routines for reading numerical data directly from file:

```
>>> years, pops = np.genfromtxt("USPopulation.txt", unpack=True, dtype=np.int)
>>> years
array([2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006])
>>> pops
array([ 51868, 153982, 156393, 158956, 161884, 165069, 168088])
```

You are now interested in changes in the population count. Assuming your data is
significantly larger than the sample above, it is recommended to use
"vectorized" operations in numpy (acting on arrays as a whole). Thus, let's pad
the population data with one zero-entry on each end:

```
>>> pops_padded = np.pad(pops, 1, 'constant')
```

Also, we take note of the original data size:

```
>>> n = len(pops)
```

The population increase can now be calculated by shifting the padded array one
index to the left and subtracting the unshifted version. Only the first `n`
entries contain valid data:

```
>>> delta = (np.roll(pops_padded, -1) - pops_padded)[:n]
>>> delta
array([ 51868, 102114,   2411,   2563,   2928,   3185,   3019])
```

You can now calculate the average increase, and the years with maximum and
minimum increase through the following numpy methods:

```
>>> int(np.average(delta))
24012
>>> years[np.argmax(delta)]
2001
>>> years[np.argmin(delta)]
2002
```

Answer (score 0):

So as you've write you have a list and want to compute average annual change, year with greatest increase and year with smallest increase. To do it you should take all changes and find average, greatest and smallest. You can do it like this:

```
numbers = [...]
sum = 0
max = 0 # every change must be more than this value
min = 9999999999 # every change must be less than this value
max_index = 0
min_index = 0
n = len(numbers)
for i in range(1, n):
    change = numbers[i] - numbers[i - 1]
    #now use change and i to update sum, max, min, max_index and min_index if necessary
```